# How to delete data from app engine with a filtered query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Here is my code fragment. This code works very fine with local development data store. But doesn't work on real app engine. The query filter used here only returns 181 rows.

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FetchOptions;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterOperator;
Query query = new Query("Share");
query.addFilter("timeOfData", FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN, sdf.parse(date));
query.setKeysOnly();
ArrayList<Key> allKeys = new ArrayList<Key>();
if(numberOfRowsToBedeletedAtOnceString != null)
 numberOfRowsToBedeletedAtOnce = Integer.parseInt(numberOfRowsToBedeletedAtOnceString);
    for (final Entity e : dcc.prepare(query).asIterable(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(numberOfRowsToBedeletedAtOnce)))
    {
      allKeys.add(e.getKey());
    }

    allKeys.trimToSize();
    dcc.delete(allKeys);
    out.print("Deleted By Date count : " + allKeys.size());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

As google documents suggests you can use **delete Entities By Query**

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Person.class); 
query.setFilter("height > maxHeightParam"); 
query.declareParameters("int maxHeightParam"); 
query.deletePersistentAll(maxHeight);
```

Check [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Delete_By_Query)

Comment: It looks like the OP is using the low level datastore API and your answer is using the JDO API.  I think the OP is looking for an answer using the low level API.

Comment: without the filter both the low level and JDO apis work fine for deleting in chinks. But when I am adding this filter, its not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by "doesn't work," specifically? is there an error message? what does it say? also, what's the value of `numberOfRowsToBedeletedAtOnce`?

if it's deadlining, or you're getting an error that says the delete is too big, try reducing `numberOfRowsToBedeletedAtOnce`.

Comment: I just tried to delete 181 rows, which is quite small I think.

Comment: it's not small if you're trying to do it in an app engine http request that's limited to 30s. remember, the app engine datastore isn't like a traditional rdbms; in particular, writes are an order of magnitude slower. operations like this that you might normally do at a sql shell won't necessarily work inside a single app engine http request.

if you really want to delete them all at once, instead of in smaller batches, try doing it in a cron job or a task queue task. the deadline on those was recently raised from 30s to 10m.